# Alphabetically Ordered Category in Wordpress

Tags: php, categories

In wordpress I'm trying to show the list of categories in a page. I'm simply using the function "wp_list_categories" to show the categories and it actually works pretty well however, I would like to have that in an alphabetically ordered list like under "**A**" (all the categories that starts with **A**). What can I do to achieve that. I don't have any php knowledge just HTML,CSS, Javascript. Any help in this regard would be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Code I'm using :

```
wp_list_categories(array(
    'style' => 'none',
    ))
```

ref: [Alphabetically ordered category list](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189917/alphabetically-ordered-category-list/264292#264292)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is a pretty well documented CMS which means at you can probably google the function name and find the answer based on parameters. If we look at the documentation of [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/#parameters) we see it has both an `order` and `orderby` which we can pass in. So, to order the categories in an alpha-numeric list we can say:

```
wp_list_categories( array(
    'style'     => 'none',
    'orderby'   => 'name',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
) );
```

You can also use DESC to change reverse order.

Comment: I'm already getting that result by default, my categories are appearing in alphabetical order but i want to put them in alphabetical sections like the categories starts with As would appear under A and Bs under "B". Thank you for responding!

Comment: @JohnD I'm still not sure I understand what you mean, this should "group" all categories that start with "A" at the top and "Z" at the bottom of the list. What is happening in your list currently that is different than what you want to happen? Feel free to [edit  your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/264305/edit) and add in more detail as there's more space than here in the comments for examples and explainations.

Comment: Sorry I might be not explaning it right. Please have a look at the ref link in my post. It has an example for the same.

Comment: @JohnD it looks like that question contains your answer, you just need to make the changes detailed in the accepted answer to the code provided in the question.

Comment: @JohnD you can easily do that. Use add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'wp_list_categories',10,2);

function wp_list_categories($args) { }

now overwrite your list categories as you expected. I am giving you an example in the answer.